# Rotate and zoom mapview at two points

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have two points on a map (MapKit), and now I want to position the map so both points are visible and aligned (one is straight above the other). I can position the map using `setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: padding, animated: true)` but I’m not sure how to make the rotation in the same call.

To illustrate a bit further, when the points on the map are side by side, I get this result when first using `setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: padding, animated: true)` and then rotating by setting `mapView.camera.heading`.

[image: result 1]

The end result I want is this:

[image: result 2]

The code I'm using to set the map rect is:

```
func centerMap() {
    let rect = MKMapRect(coordinates: [currentHole!.teeCoordinate, currentHole!.greenCoordinate])
    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: padding, animated: true)
}

extension MKMapRect {
    init(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
        let points = coordinates.map { MKMapPoint.init($0) }
        let rects = points.map { MKMapRect(origin: $0, size: MKMapSize(width: 0, height: 0)) }
        self = rects.reduce(MKMapRect.null) { result, rect in
            return result.union(rect)
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using MKMapCamera instead.

Comment: I am having this same issue, but I still want to keep the two points shown on the map while rotating. How did you still keep the points on the map and rotate at the same time?